# How can I describe the colour of a thing?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How can I describe the colour of a thing?

The thing looks red to A, but it looks green to B, so I think it can’t be described as “a green thing” or “a red thing.”

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain. (more context, off topic etc.)

Comment: *Pigment* is an inherent physical property of objects—you can take a sample of a substance and perform spectrometry on it and see what pigmentation it has. But *color* is a subjective perception of light and how it interacts with an animal's light receptors. So if two people think an object has very different colors it would be difficult to say with certainty that its color is one or the other.

Comment: There are marginal cases, where colors may be classified differently by different people, but in most cases, if the color is vivid, and the observers aren't color-blind, people who speak the same language will agree on what the name of the color is. That's why we have words for colors, after all.

Comment: [Color blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) or daltonism, the inability to identify or distinguish certain colors. If something is normally green (e.g. grass, the leaves of a tree in summer) it cannot be red for someone else unless they're Picasso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native English speaker here.

In English, it is fine for Person A to describe an object as "a red thing", even if Person B thinks it looks green instead. Person B could simply respond, "No, it's green!" and the two of them could have a discussion. So if an object appears red to you, you can go ahead and describe it as red. I agree with the commenter who says it's difficult to be certain about what color the thing really is. However, by convention, we express our perception of a color as a certainty.